# Проблемы с работой методов через сервер Red5

Tags: java, red5

Я использую сервер Red5.Написал приложение, которое режет и клеит музыку. Запуская локально это приложение, методы выполняют свои функции. Когда я передаю путь к файлу с клиента (Flex) на сервер, методы возвращают неудачу. Использую потоки FileInputStream. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так ошибка-то какая? Что говорит?

Comment: он ничего не говорит. Просто при вызове с клиента метода выдает NetStream.call.Failed

Comment: Так на серверной стороне посмотрите.. ясное дело, что не клиенте ничего не будет

Comment: В том то и проблема. На сервере выдает неправильные значения. Хотя при прямом вызове методов (не с клиента) все работает отлично

Comment: ну, у вас есть там какие-нибудь логи сервера, где можно увидеть стектрейсы?

Comment: нет

Comment: Такого не может быть.

Comment: значит надо поискать получше.

Comment: Либо покрутить конфиги сервера, чтобы понять, как настрены логгеры и куда уходит аутпут. Или подключитесь к нему отладчиком на худой конец..

Comment: надо будет попробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете с клиента локальный путь к файлу на клиентской машине? В таком случае сервер и не должен иметь доступа файлам. Вам, наверно, стоит каким-либо образом закачать файл на сервер, проделать с ним операции и вернуть обработанный клиенту.

Comment: я передаю имя файла. На сервере дописывается стандартный путь к каталогу на винчестере, в котором лежит файл

Comment: по идее должно работать, но увы

Comment: винчестер сервера? Или это какой-то расшаренный ресурс?

Comment: это мой компъютер. Клиент и сервер на одном пк

Comment: я передаю с клиента строку. Затем на сервере создаю новый объект потока FileInputStream и передаю ее на обработку методов, которые используют JLayer